# How to connect input value to unnamed argument in function

Tags: r, function

I would like to create a function so that a quantile will be calculated from a vector convered from a dataframe. I encountered difficult in applying df[[]] to create a vector from dataframe.

The function code is shown below:

```
Q <- function (df, type, ...){
             switch(type,
                  vec <- df[["..."]]) 
           if (is.numeric(vec)) {
              stop ("This is not a numeric vector")
                      } else {
          Quant <-  
             data.frame(quantile(vec,na.rm=TRUE))[4:2, ] 
                      }
 }
```

I tried to apply column B of thedataframe which contains some "NA", df to this function using the code: Q(df, "B")
The results show #NA NA NA. My concern is how different columns of the dataframe can be applied to the function.

I feel like the function needs to be revised. Can anybody help solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this function -

```
Q <- function (df, type){
  vec <- df[[type]]
  if (!is.numeric(vec)) {
    stop ("This is not a numeric vector")
  } else {
    Quant <-  data.frame(vec = quantile(vec,na.rm=TRUE))
  }
  Quant
}

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A = letters[1:5], B = c(rnorm(4), NA), C = rnorm(5))
Q(df, 'A')
```

> Error in Q(df, "A") : This is not a numeric vector

```
Q(df, 'B')
#             vec
#0%   -0.56047565
#25%  -0.31275203
#50%  -0.07983455
#75%   0.44255837
#100%  1.55870831

Q(df, 'C')
#            vec
#0%   -1.2650612
#25%  -0.6868529
#50%   0.1292877
#75%   0.4609162
#100%  1.7150650
```

Comment: Great idea! Thanks for your help.